# How can I "bubble up" events in a Backbone View hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, backbone.js

I have a backbone app with a view structure that looks like the following - note that I've removed implementations, models, collections, etc. for brevity:

```
NewsListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $('li#newspane'),

    // This is what I would like to be able to do
    // events: { 'filtered': 'reset' }

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
    },

    render: function() {
    },

    reset: function(){
    }

});

FilterView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $('li.filter'),

    initialize: function() {
    },

    render: function() {
    },

    toggleFilter: function() {
    }

});

AllView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {

        this.newsListView = new NewsListView();
        this.filterView = new FilterView();

    }

});
```

Essentially, whenever the `FilterView`'s `toggleFilter()` function is called, I would like to fire off an event called `filtered` or something like that that is then caught by the `NewsListView`, which then calls its `reset()` function. Without passing a reference of a `NewsListView` object to my `FilterView`, I'm not sure how to send it an event. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track. It sounds like what you need is a global event dispatcher.  There  a decent article and example here: http://www.michikono.com/2012/01/11/adding-a-centralized-event-dispatcher-on-backbone-js/

Comment: The link is dead. This link should be the same as found on the internet archive https://web.archive.org/web/20150225004842/https://michikono.com/2012/01/11/adding-a-centralized-event-dispatcher-on-backbone-js/

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to do this using the already available functionality of jquery events and the backbone events property.

For example, instead of doing this from inside your subview:

```
this.trigger("yourevent", this);
```

do this instead:

```
this.$el.trigger("yourevent", this);
```

Then in any view that is a parent, grandparent, etc of your child view, listen for the event on that view's $el by defining a property on that view's events object:

```
events:{
    "yourevent":"yourhandler"
}
```

and define the handler on that view as well:

```
yourhandler:function(subview) {
}
```

So this way, a view doesn't need to know about what descendant views exist, only the type of event it is interested in.  If the view originating the event is destroyed, nothing needs to change on the ancestor view.  If the ancestor view is destroyed, Backbone will detach the handlers automatically.

Caveat: I haven't actually tried this out yet, so there may be a gotcha in there somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the aha! moment.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the Backbone.Courier plugin as bubbling events is a perfect use case:

https://github.com/dgbeck/backbone.courier

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found to trigger and listen to events is to just use the Backbone object itself. It already has the events functions mixed in to it, so you can just trigger eg:

```
Backbone.trigger('view:eventname',{extra_thing:whatever, thing2:whatever2});
```

then, *in any other backbone view in your app*, you can listen for this event eg:

```
Backbone.on('view:eventname', function(passed_obj) {
    console.log(passed_obj.extra_thing);
});
```

I'm not exactly sure what the advantage is in not using the Backbone object as your event handler, and instead creating a separate object to do it, but for quick-and-dirty work, the above works fine. HTH!

NOTE: one disadvantage to this is that every listener will "hear" every single event triggered in this way. Not sure what the big O is on that, but work being careful to not overload your views with lots of this stuff. Again: this is quick and dirty! :)

Comment: Great solution- I use this instead of a long-winded approach of bubbling up to "grandparents".

Answer (score 0):

So, I came up a with a solution - create an object that extends `Backbone.Events`, and pass it as a parameter to multiple views. This almost feels like message passing between actors, or something. Anyway - I'm posting this as an answer in case anybody else needs a quick solution, but I'm not going to accept the answer. This feels hacky. I'd still like to see a better solution.

```
NewsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('li#newspane'),

    // Too bad this doesn't work, it'd be really convenient
    // events: { 'filtered': 'reset' }

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
        // but at least this does
        this.options.eventProxy.bind('filtered', this.reset);
    },
    render: function() {},
    reset: function() {}
});

FilterView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('li.filter'),

    initialize: function() {},
    render: function() {},
    toggleFilter: function() {
        this.options.eventProxy.trigger('filtered');
    }
});

AllView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        var eventProxy = {};
        _.extend(eventProxy, Backbone.Events);
        this.newsListView = new NewsListView({eventProxy: eventProxy});
        this.filterView = new FilterView({eventProxy: eventProxy});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved using small backbone.js hack. Simply modify Backbone.Events.trigger for passing events to the `this.parent`

```
if this.parent != null
```